# Uitableview cell appending one on one when doing scrolling down with different size for the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi every one before thinking this as dumb question take a look. Actually am using custom cell with xib and i want to show image , text and posted date in a cell if image is not there i should show only text and posted date alone. But problem is when i scroll down the cell getting collapse one on one but when i scroll up its looks fine. I don where am doing wrong calculation. Please some one guide me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
        static  NSString *identifier = @"TableViewCell";



        HomeViewMsgCell *cell = [messageTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


        if (cell==nil)
        {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HomeViewMsgCell" owner:self options:nil];

            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    NSString *_imageUriString=[dealImageArray  objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *imageUriSubString=[_imageUriString  substringToIndex:5];


    if ([[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isEqualToString:@"/Deals/Tile/deal.png"] )
    {
        cell.posteImageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        cell.postContentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 280, 50);
        cell.postedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 170, 30);
    }

    else if ( [[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]isEqualToString:@"/BizImages/Tile/.jpg" ])

    {
        NSString *imageStringUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",appDelegate.apiUri,[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        [cell.posteImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStringUrl]];

        cell.postContentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 90, 280, 50);
        cell.postedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 140, 170, 30);

    }

    else if ([imageUriSubString isEqualToString:@"local"])
    {

        NSString *imageStringUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] substringFromIndex:5]];

        cell.posteImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageStringUrl];
        cell.postContentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 90, 280, 50);
        cell.postedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 140, 170, 30);

    }

    else
    {
        NSString *imageStringUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",appDelegate.apiUri,[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        [cell.posteImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStringUrl]];
        cell.postContentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 90, 280, 50);
        cell.postedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 140, 170, 30);



    }


    NSString *dateString=[dealDateArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] ];
    NSDate *date;


    if ([dateString hasPrefix:@"/Date("])
    {
        dateString=[dateString substringFromIndex:5];
        dateString=[dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-1];
        date=[self getDateFromJSON:dateString];

    }
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, yyyy"];

    NSString *dealDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSString *text = [dealDescriptionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *stringData;

    if ([[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isEqualToString:@"/Deals/Tile/deal.png"])
    {
        stringData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@\n",text,dealDate];
    }


    else if ( [[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]isEqualToString:@"/BizImages/Tile/.jpg" ])
    {
        stringData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@\n",text,dealDate];
    }

    else
    {

        version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

        if ([version floatValue]<7.0)
        {
            stringData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n%@\n\n%@\n",text,dealDate];
        }


        else
        {
            stringData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n%@\n\n%@\n",text,dealDate];
        }

    }


    [cell.postContentLabel setText:text];

      cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *_imageUriString=[dealImageArray  objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *imageUriSubString=[_imageUriString  substringToIndex:5];


    if ([[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isEqualToString:@"/Deals/Tile/deal.png"] )
    {
        return 100;
    }

    else if ( [[dealImageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]isEqualToString:@"/BizImages/Tile/.jpg" ])

    {

        return 190;
    }

    else if ([imageUriSubString isEqualToString:@"local"])
    {

        return 190;
    }

    else
    {
        return 190;

    }

    return 190;

}
```

and am adding the image for refference [image]

you can see here the cell issue. some one can help me. thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying frames of labels in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. So the next time when the cell gets re used it ends up with the previous frame settings.

Options:

- Avoid messing up frames so that each cell will have the default frame as designed in StoryBoard/XiB's/Code.
- If you cannot avoid changing frames, atleast reset them in `prepareForReuse` of your custom `UITableViewCell` class to original settings.

Comment: actually if i don have image i have to move the label to top so only am ding that